# React native maps marker on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm having problems with a creation of a custom view on the markers in Android.

It is a marker with a custom icon and a view with text positioned on top of the marker, absolute. This is how it looks on iOs (and how it's supposed to look).

[image: marker iOs]

But on Android the look is completely different. I am aware that it is because Android handles markers differently, but nevertheless want to achieve the same result and can't figure out a way.

Looks on Android:

[image: marker Android]

It is cut off at width of custom image of the marker.

One option would be to supply the width to the view wrapping the image and the view with the text, but if this is done, it only goes to the right (giving negative left does not help) and the markers stop being anchored.

[image: marker Android]

The question: how to copy iOs behaviour on Android?

The code for the marker is as follows:

```
return (
    <MapViewMarker
      coordinate={{
        latitude: props.vehicle.lat,
        longitude: props.vehicle.lng,
      }}
      anchor={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }}
      onPress={props.onMarkerPress}
      stopPropagation
      style={styles.markerStyling}
      tracksViewChanges={tracksViewChangesState}
    >
      <View style={styles.imageViewStyling}>
        <Image
          source={props.image}
          style={styles.flatMarker}
          onLoad={stopTrackingViewChanges}
        />
        {props.showBattery && (
          <View style={[styles.batteryContainer, urgent
            ? styles.batteryContainerUrgent
            : styles.batteryContainerNonUrgent,
          { borderColor: urgent ? COLOR_RED_MARKER_BORDER : props.borderColor }]}
          >
            <Text
              style={[
                styles.batteryText, urgent
                  ? styles.batteryTextUrgent
                  : styles.batteryTextNonUrgent]}
              ellipsizeMode="tail"
              numberOfLines={1}
            >
              {renderMarkerText()}
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </MapViewMarker>
  ); 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flatMarker: {
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
  },
  batteryContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    paddingVertical: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 1 : 0,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  batteryContainerNonUrgent: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: COLOR_WHITE,
  },
  batteryContainerUrgent: {
    width: '300%',
    left: -25,
    backgroundColor: COLOR_RED_MARKER,
    zIndex: 30,
  },
  batteryText: {
    fontFamily: FONT_AVENIR_BLACK,
  },
  batteryTextUrgent: {
    color: COLOR_WHITE,
    fontSize: 9,
  },
  batteryTextNonUrgent: {
    color: COLOR_BLACK,
    fontSize: 8,
  },
  markerStyling: {
    zIndex: 20,
  },
  imageViewStyling: {
    paddingVertical: 8,
  },
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for inspiration, I've finally solved it giving `display: flex` and a fixed width to the encapsulating view, and then treating the marker and the box as its children in terms of the styling, like so:

```
imageViewStyling: {
    paddingVertical: 8,
    width: 100,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```